# Rails Attributes not saving to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, psql

I'm using psql with my rails 4 app.

I have had a working projects model for quite some time, but with a recent change to a model that is entirely unrelated, I now have a problem that means that my project form attributes are not being created. I look in the console and the attributes are marked 'nil' even though I complete them in the new project form.

The form elements are not saving.

I have a projects model controller with permitted params as follows:

```
  def new
    #authorise @project
    @project = Project.new
    @project.scope = Scope.new
    @project.scope.datum = Datum.new
    @project.scope.material = Material.new
    @project.scope.mentoring = Mentoring.new
    @project.scope.participant = Participant.new
    @project.scope.funding = Funding.new
    @project.scope.ethic = Ethic.new
    @project.scope.group_research = GroupResearch.new
    @project.scope.backgroundip = Backgroundip.new

  end
```

I have some nested attributes from other models. Project params include both project attributes and nested attributes.

```
def project_params
      params[:project].permit(
      :title, :description, :video_proposal, :link_to_video_proposal, :draft, 
      :expiry_date_for_sponsor_interest,  :motivation, :approach,
      :results, :completion_date, :start_date, :industry_id, :public, :recurring_project,
      :frequency, :date_for_student_invitation, :date_for_student_interest, :closed, :student_objective, 
      :industry_relevance, :hero_image, :report, :standard_licence, :bespoke_licence, :bespoke_licence_form,
      :research_consulting, :other_outcome,
      scope_attributes: [:data, :materials, :mentoring, :participants, :participants, :funding, :ethics, :group, :project_id,
                         datum_attributes: [:prim_sec, :qual_quant, :survey, :survey_link, :experiment, :other_type, :other_description,
                                           :confidential, :data_description, :scope_id],
                         material_attributes: [:mattype, :description, :scope_id],
                         mentoring_attributes: [:frequency, :description, :scope_id],
                         funding_attributes: [ :expenses, :honorarium, :financing, :currency, :size, :amount_expenses, :amount_honorarium,
                                  :amount_principal_financing, :return_on_finance, :period_of_return, :expense_description, :scope_id],
                         participant_attributes: [ :title, :description, :location, :costs, :participation_cost, :eligibility, :eligibility_criteria,
                            :location_specific, :scope_id, :currency ],
                         group_research_attributes: [:number_of_group_members, :scope_id],
                         ethic_attributes: [:obtained, :date_expected, :ethics_comment, :ethics_policy_link, :scope_id],
                         backgroundip_attributes: [:scope_id, :copyright, :design, :patent, :trademark, :geographical_indication,
                                                   :trade_secret, :other, :identifier_copyright, :identifier_design, :identifier_patent,
                                                   :identifier_trademark, :identifier_geographical_indication, :identifier_trade_secret,
                                                   :identifier_other, :description, :registered_owner, :unregistered_interest, :conditions ]
                        ]
      )

      params.require(:project).permit(:link_to_video_proposal)

    end
```

I have a project new form which has:

```
      <%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
      <% if @project.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>Looks like there might be <%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> with this project proposal. Take a look and let us know if we can help to sort them out.</h2>
        <% end %>
        <ul>
          <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="headerquestion-project">Project Overview
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
      <%= f.label  'Project title',   :class => 'question-project' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <%= f.input :title, label: false,  placeholder: 'A catchy, relevant title for your project', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 100%', class: 'response-project'} %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I try to complete the form and press submit, I get an error saying that title cannot be blank. I add a title, press submit and the view does not show the title and the console shows that the title did not save.

Any ideas as to how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Try to remove the last line from `project_params` (`params.require(:project).permit(:link_to_video_proposal)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding permitted parameters. You need to write you `project_params` method something like this:

```
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit( 
      ...
      ...
    )
end
```

**Note** that I have used `params.require(:project)` instead of directly accessing params like hash (`params[:project]`) and have removed your last statement from this method which was overriding the permitted parameters.

Another thing, try to avoid using **public** as an attribute/column name. This is a reserved keyword of ruby.

Comment: Actually, I just created a migration to rename the public column to disclosed. I changed the controller param and the form and show views. However, I now get an error saying that public is an undefined method. I can't understand that because I don't use public anywhere.

Comment: You should add another question for this to isolate current ques & to avoid fading this question out.